Loop in MaxEnt (R dismo package) not using all data points when running replicates
I'm running a MaxEnt model using the dismo package in R. I have a relatively small dataset (36 presence points), and would like to run cross-validated replicates. My plan is to divide my points into 6 equally sized groups of 6. Since (from my understanding) cross-validation uses one group of datapoints to test the model in each replicate, I want to make sure each group gets used as the tester at least once. However, there is something wrong with my loop, and it discards some data. I think it might be something about the interaction between kfold(), dividing the points into training and testing, and running cross-validated replicates, but I'm not sure.
Here's a reproducible example:
library(dismo)
##### Set up data #####
fnames <- list.files(path=paste(system.file(package="dismo"), '/ex', sep=''), 
                     pattern='grd', full.names=TRUE ) #get raster predictors
predictors <- stack(fnames) #make raster predictors into a stack so you can process them all together
#plot(predictors)

# file with presence points
occurence <- paste(system.file(package="dismo"), '/ex/bradypus.csv', sep='') #get 116 presence points
occ <- read.table(occurence, header=TRUE, sep=',')[,-1] #put presence points into a table

# Create cross validation folds
fold <- kfold(occ, k=5) #divide the presence points into 5 groups

# background data
bg <- randomPoints(predictors, 1000) #create 1000 points for the model to predict against
# Loop through each cross validation to ensure the entire data set is considered
for (k in 1:5){ #run through each fold set but kfold()
  
  # Force R to ensure each cross validation
  occtest <- occ[fold == k, ] #if the datapoint was assigned the same number that the loop is on by kfold, use that in testing; should be 23 points
  occtrain <- occ[fold != k, ] #if the datapoint wasn't assigned the same number that the loop is on by kfold, use that in training the model; should be 93 points
  #str(occtest) #check how many observations there are
  #print(paste0(k)) #tell which loop it's on
  
  me2 <- maxent(predictors, #use the rasters as predictor values
                occtrain, #use the training points as occurrence data
                factors='biome', #specify which predictor rasters should be considered as categorical
                args=c('replicates=10', #run the model 10 times
                       'replicatetype=crossvalidate')) #use the crossvalidation method
}

When you run this, you get an html page for each replicate, and each of those replicates says:
"The follow settings were used during the run:
71 presence records used for training, 8 for testing.
9758 points used to determine the Maxent distribution (background points and presence points)."
I don't understand why it uses a total of 79 points when it should be using a total of 116.
I've also tried using just occ as the occurrence variable to see if it's an issue with the way occtrain is made:
library(dismo)
##### Set up data #####
fnames <- list.files(path=paste(system.file(package="dismo"), '/ex', sep=''), 
                     pattern='grd', full.names=TRUE ) #get raster predictors
predictors <- stack(fnames) #make raster predictors into a stack so you can process them all together
#plot(predictors)

# file with presence points
occurence <- paste(system.file(package="dismo"), '/ex/bradypus.csv', sep='') #get 116 presence points
occ <- read.table(occurence, header=TRUE, sep=',')[,-1] #put presence points into a table

# Create cross validation folds
fold <- kfold(occ, k=5) #divide the presence points into 5 groups

# background data
bg <- randomPoints(predictors, 1000) #create 1000 points for the model to predict against
# Loop through each cross validation to ensure the entire data set is considered
for (k in 1:5){ #run through each fold set but kfold()
  
  # Force R to ensure each cross validation
  occtest <- occ[fold == k, ] #if the datapoint was assigned the same number that the loop is on by kfold, use that in testing; should be 23 points
  occtrain <- occ[fold != k, ] #if the datapoint wasn't assigned the same number that the loop is on by kfold, use that in training the model; should be 93 points
  #str(occtest) #check how many observations there are
  #print(paste0(k)) #tell which loop it's on
  
  me2 <- maxent(predictors, #use the rasters as predictor values
                occ, #use all points as occurrence data
                factors='biome', #specify which predictor rasters should be considered as categorical
                args=c('replicates=10', #run the model 10 times
                       'replicatetype=crossvalidate')) #use the crossvalidation method
}

And that gives 10 replicate pages that all read:
"
The follow settings were used during the run:
85 presence records used for training, 9 for testing.
9757 points used to determine the Maxent distribution (background points and presence points)."
It's more points, but it still isn't all of them, and I don't understand why it's using 94 points here.
Basically: What's wrong with my loop that MaxEnt/R doesn't use all of my presence points?
